# Appropriate symbol to denote feasible region

Tags: optimization, notation

I have an optimization problem such as
$$
\min_{x\in\mathop{Range}(\mathbf A) \text{ s.t. } \mathbf B x = b} \|x\|
$$
which I would like to write more concisely as
$$
\min_{x\in\mathcal{X}} \|x\|
$$
where $\mathcal{X} = \{x \in \mathrm{Range}(A) : \mathbf{B}x = b\}$.

**What symbol is traditionally used in place of $\mathcal{X}$ to denote the set of feasible $x$?**

If the answer depends on whether the constraint set is linear or nonlinear, I am interested in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

Step two<sup>1</sup> in "how to do a math problem": label the parts of the problem.  So give the set you want a name.

"Let $S = \{x \in \mathrm{Range}(A) : \mathbf{B}x = b\}$.  ... 
$$  \min_{x \in S} ||x||  $$
... "

<sup>1 : The number of this step in any particular "how to do a math problem" may vary.</sup>

Comment: My question seems to have been unclear, so I've edited it. I'm aware that I can choose any letter or symbol I want to represent the feasible region ($S$ in your example, $\mathcal X$ in mine). I am looking for the canonical symbol used in practice (i.e. in optimization papers)

Comment: @Moormanly : It is an error to believe that obscure symbology communicates clearly.  If you don't know the symbol, you should not imagine that your reader does.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will make sure to introduce the symbol clearly, whatever it is (e.g. $\mathcal{X} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \{x \in \mathrm{Range}(A) : \mathbf{B}x = b\}$). In any case, there are two benefits to using the canonical notation instead of choosing one arbitrarily myself: 
(1) It will introduce readers who are unfamiliar with the area to the most commonly used symbol 
(2) It will avoid confusing readers who are intimately familiar with the canonical notation.